# Xubuntu title bar default settings

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, xfwm4

I reset xfwm4 from settings editor. Right clicked on xfwm4 and hit reset. After doing that my title bar won't function properly. I noticed my window buttons changed also the command i use to have dark title bar:

```
    env GTK2_RC_FILES="/usr/share/themes/elementary Dark/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
```

does not work anymore.

I need to revert back to default Xubuntu settings somehow. Before restarting title bar was always white even when using dark themes.

Edit: Sharing more info on the matter.
Firstly i think my title bar -using numix theme- was kind of dark before resetting. Also my window buttons were different. Now i see only a cross, before it was a circled cross.

Before options part on title bar was not present even if i set it to O , now it is there when i use O.

I believe some other part was managing my title bar and i just broke that connection.

Comment: What about changing to a gtk3 theme?

Comment: Reset with this as regular user (no sudo) 'xfce4-panel --quit ; pkill xfconfd ; rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml ; xfce4-panel;'

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I can't really see how that would help though. But i tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I was referring to first comment. Second one didn't work either.

Comment: Did you reboot after the command? Another option is rm -r ~/.config/xfce4 and then reboot

Comment: I didn't, will do right away. However i have no hope, because i already restarted after this thing happened. Before restarting it was worse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75425/discussion-between-anonim-and-arijit-chatterjee).

Answer (score 1):

The XFCE desktop settings for the panels are stored in your home in `~/.config/xfce4/` and you should have the default home files for new users in `/etc/skek/`.

So you could "reset" your settings by copying the files from `/etc/skel/.config/xfce4/` to your `/.config/xfce4/` directory.

Then just logging out & in again should reload your desktop (reboot not required).

Using XFCE's own settings windows to change things (themes in Appearance, Desktop, etc) should work.

---

Since you said there are no files in `/etc/skel/.config/xfce4/`, you should be able to just erase your current xfce4 files in `~/.config/xfce4/` (possibly using a 2nd account, in case erasing the files while you're logged in might cause them to be re-written on logout) and things should be reset on the next login.

Comment: There is no xfce4 file in /etc/skel/.config/

Answer (score 0):

I just realised i had to use window manager to change title bar theme. I'm silly, it would be much appreciated if this whole topic is removed.

Comment: You mean you used "*XFCE's own settings windows to change things (themes in Appearance, Desktop, etc)*"? That was part of my original answer, if it helped you should upvote it or select it as correct